is it correct to say "push the table by its far edge"?

My daughter put her hands in the middle of the edge of the table and pushed a table, which was hard to move the table.
So, I told her to put her hands on one end of the edges and push the table, then do the same thing on the other end.
is it correct to say "push the table by its far edge"?

What was the problem with saying that?  Did she not understand? Do you have any particular concerns?  There's no particular "correct" way to say this, so this is a bit "proofreading" at the moment.

the far edge of the table is nonsense in the cited context, because if it refers to anything, that would be on the opposite side (the right-hand side of the diagram). Or feasibly if a thoughtless speaker was located at the top of the diagram, he might mean the bottom edge (furthest away from him). But especially when talking to a child, that would be thoughtless.

You could say

When you push the table, push closer to the corner.
When you push the table, push near the corner.

"And then do the same at the other end"


push the table by its far edge

Far edge refers to the edge opposite the one next to the girl; whereas, near edge is the one she has her hands on.  We could say push the table by the two ends of the edge; do it one end at a time.

It is a stretch to imagine that a father would say that to kid, or to another adult. Generally, we refer to this/that and point.

In American English, at least, you might hear

Move one end at a time.
Scoot one end at a time.
Slide one end at a time.
Push one end at a time.
Move/scoot/etc. one end (of the table) and then the other.
Wiggle it back and forth to put it where you want it.
Kind of wiggle it to get it there.

As the last suggests, I don’t know that English has a word for the specific technique you wanted to recommend. More precise might be

Translate it by alternating slight rotations of the ends.

but that sounds extraordinarily robotic and assumes that she wants to translate, which means no rotation but a lateral slide. A more general but still robotic phrasing is

Reposition it by sliding each side in turn until the table is how you want it.

Slide assumes the table is on a smooth surface and not carpet, for example. In that case, you might suggest

Pick up and rotate one side then the other.


Move one end for a time for a table? I dunno. This is about pushing the table. Everything you're saying is much too technical.

Pragmatically, we'd say these:
(Please look up pragmatics in linguistics)
First, it makes no sense.
Second, we'd use something like this:
Push it from one edge and then the other.
Presumably, you are pointing at it when you say this.
OR
Push it from the edge closest to you, then the other.
So, there is also a deictic dimension to all this. (Deixis is also useful when learning English as it covers reference to pointing in speech, for example.)

The far edge of the universe is decribed in The Hitchhiker's Guide to the Galaxy.
The far (southeast) edge of that town is a dangerous neighborhood.


One AI chatbot says "Push the table from the edge" might mean to push the table away from the edge of something else.

@Tom chatbots are not good for deictics and pragmatics. They don't point or see or refer to previous speech.  And no, push the table from the edge is NOT from the edge of something else. That'd be: Push the table away from the edge [of the stage, for example].
